# Caption for a listing

Tags: formatting, listings, captions

I have captions on each of my listings. Each caption is prefaced with "Listing # [text]" where # is the number of the listing. Each caption is centered over my listing. How can I modify the options of these captions? Here is a visual:[image]

1. I want to get truncate the caption to only contain [text]
2. I want to move the position of the caption from the center towards the left-side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If a listing has a `title`, it will be used instead of `caption`, but without "Listing #" line.
2. Unfortunately centered titles are hardcoded into listings, so you need to change the code.  Here is a solution:  I've just took the package defined `\@makecaption` and deleted the secong `\hfil` and added `\bfseries` (note that `\lst@maketitle` uses `\@makecaption` and drops the first part.  If you want to keept captions centered but titles left-aligned, you need to patch `\lst@maketitle` rather than `\@maketitle`).

Here us the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \bfseries #1: #2\par
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[title={Some listing}]
a=b
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The following post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117531/styling-a-lstlisting-caption-using-caption-package provide a way of styling caption that can easily be modified to have left sided caption