# Is it possible to use a non-monospace font in verbatim environments?

Tags: fonts, listings, verbatim

I know it runs contrary to a lot of the point, but I'd like to experiment with different fonts to see which I like better. I can't seem to find any reference to a way to do this, if it's at all possible.

---

Edit:

I ended up using the following. It's better, but not quite to the point of what I'd like

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[scaled]{beramono}
```

The big problem I have is that I find the monospace fonts to be too spaced out, making text take up a lot more space on the line. If anybody has any other suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Are you referring to the standard `verbatim` environment or to the `lstlisting` environment? (I ask you this because of this other question of yours: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117531/styling-a-lstlisting-caption-using-caption-package).

Comment: I'm referring to the listings... I figured I'd add a reference to verbatim though as I figured it would better get the point across.

Comment: Regarding the spacing, take a look at the `columns` option; an example at the end of my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package, you can use the `basicstyle` key to control the font attributes for normal text in the code; some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\itshape]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small\ttfamily]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\Large\normalfont]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, these modifications are better made globally using `\lstset` in the preamble:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily}
```

You can also use the `columns` key to control spacing; an example showing the four available values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=fixed]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=flexible]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=fullflexible]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\sffamily,columns=spaceflexible]
Some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, a global setting is preferable; for example:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  columns=fullflexible
}
```

Comment: For a package solution, `fancyvrb` may be more suitable.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
I know it runs contrary to a lot of the point, 
but I'd like to experiment with different fonts to see 
which I like better. 
I can't seem to find any reference to a way to do this, 
if it's at all possible.
\end{verbatim}

\makeatletter
%\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\itshape}
\makeatother

\begin{verbatim}
I know it runs contrary to a lot of the point, 
but I'd like to experiment with different fonts to see 
which I like better. 
I can't seem to find any reference to a way to do this, 
if it's at all possible.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX defines

```
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}
```

so

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeatother
```

would make it use sans. Note if you are using OT1 encoding then most of the non tt fonts do not have the expected glyphs for ascii characters like `<` so you probably want to use T1 encoding (which is a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 1):

While this is a few more steps to set up, it piggybacks onto the verbatimbox package (which normally sets verbatim in a box) giving you a convenient invocation mechanism, as an optional argument to the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{verblist}{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{-1}%
  \let\my@par\par%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    \@tmp\setbox0=\hbox{\@tmp\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\my@par}}%
\verbatim\verbbox@inner%
}
{\endverbatim\global\def\@tmp{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{verblist}[\sffamily]
this is a test
of the verblist environment
in a sans serif font
\end{verblist}

\begin{verblist}[\rmfamily\itshape]
this is a test
of the verblist environment
in a roman italic font
\end{verblist}


\end{document}
```

[image]