# Automatic line and page breaking - how to turn it off?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 , I want to turn off automatic line and page breaking , I was trying to use {verbatim} , {alltt} and \verb+...+ , it works , but doesn't keep original font (I am using gfsartemisia-euler font , from here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsartemisia-euler/). Can anybody help?
I need solution with keeping original formating of math's formulas. For example: I don't want  to see \int instead of traditional symbol of an integral.  Problem can be solved by \nopagebreak or \nolinebreak, but using them is rather burdensome.

Comment: So can your question be reformulated as "How can use a different font with `verbatim`?" If that's the case, see [Is it possible to use a non-monospace font in `verbatim` environments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117533/5764)

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the output is meant to be here? You _do_ want for example maths formulae rendering, but want to break every line by hand. That sounds rather unusual: do you have a specific example you could point us to?

Comment: $(z-t_0)^n$ and $(A-t_0\cdot E)^n, A\cdot t_0 \cdot E = t_0\cdot\nolinebreak E\cdot\nolinebreak A = \nolinebreak t_0\cdot\nolinebreak A$ \nolinebreak we\ \nolinebreak have:\\ 6 x \nolinebreak it's definitely too much.

Comment: You could put each line into an \mbox{}, but you probably just need to reduce the font size until it fits.

Comment: It's useful and works , but problem of turning off automatic page breaking is still not solved. Put a recipe of solution of the problem and I'll mark it , green.